# remove sigle quotes from the output and keep type to <class 'list'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to remove single quotes from the output:

```
['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3', 'doc4', 'doc5']
```

And keep type to "list".

I've tried, but I got 'str'.

```
doclist = []
for i in range(5): 
    list_doc_num = 'doc'+str(i+1)
    doclist.append(list_doc_num)

print(doclist)
print(type(doclist))
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue? `print` adds the single quotes when you are printing a list but its just formatting. if you want to see without quotes you can print each item individually in your `for` loop

Comment: Sorry but what does "and keep type to" mean?

Comment: I want its type as <class 'list'> too but my text is not completed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the single quote from the output:

```
print('[', ', '.join(doclist), ']', sep='')
```

Output:

```
[doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5]
```

Comment: I assign a = '[', ', '.join(doclist), ']', sep='' .its type change to "str" but i need "list"

Comment: So why don't you just `print` it without assigning it to a variable. It will still remain the `list`. I've just changed the format of the list. Because when you print the `list` as it is it will display the single quotes to represent the string.

Comment: I need to put it to assignment because I want this list to point to my input in the file ... like doc1="aaaaaa ddddd fffff" doc2=" kkkk llll iiii "

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print('['+', '.join(doclist)+']')
```

Comment: I need to keep type as "list" but i got "str"

Comment: a = '['+', '.join(doclist)+']' .....I need to keep type as "list" but i got "str"

Comment: You are trying to create a list of objects? Do those object already exists in the code and now you need to iterate through them based on file or user input?